# Erro JavaScript ao usar Action

Tags: javascript, html, magento, prototypejs

Estou tentando usar uma funcionalidade da plataforma que eu uso (magento) só que não estou conseguindo, está sendo retornado o seguinte erro da imagem. Eu quero enviar newsletter pelo mobile, então eu tentei copiar a mesma action e tudo mais, só que não estou conseguindo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solução:**

Como o magento é uma plataforma que usa controllers, blocos e helpers, ele "facilita" muito a interação de seus módulos, o que eu estava tentando fazer era puxar uma ação fora daquele modulo, onde era setado no XML, logo eu coloquei o código que está na imagem dentro do módulo, setando apenas outro layout/css para o mobile, mas conseguindo assim a mesma funcionalidade. O meu erro foi tentar utilizar a Action fora do modulo.